# Valid select query returns Not a group by expression error when used with Insert Statement

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to implement the following query:

```
INSERT
INTO sales_data_arch
 (
   order_date,
   orderId,
   orderName,
   state,   
   hour,
   product,
   cardNo,
   amount,
   createdon,
   createdby
 )
WITH vw_product AS
 (select * from productTable 
where group_name = 'Product_ABC'
 ),
   vw_cardDetails AS
 (
 select * from cardDetailsTable 
 where group_name = 'Product_Card_Details'
 ),
 vw_sales AS
 (SELECT sd.order_date order_date,
sd.order_id,
   sd.hour,
   vp.product_name,
   gtm.cardNo ,
   SUM(sd.amount) amount_total
 FROM productSalesData  sd
 LEFT JOIN vw_product vp
 ON sd.productId = vp.productId

LEFT JOIN vw_cardDetails gtm
 ON sd.transactionId     = gtm.transactionId

 WHERE order_Date = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'yyyymmdd')

 GROUP BY sd.order_date,
   sd.order_id,
   sd.hour,
   vp.product_name,
   gtm.cardNo
 )
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(order_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-MM-yy') order_date,
 orderId,
 orderName,
 ro.state,
   hour,
 product_name product,

 cardNo,
 amount_total amount,
 SYSDATE createdon,
 'task_scheduler' createdby,
 null
FROM vw_sales con
LEFT JOIN stateTable ro
ON con.stateId   = ro.stateId
WHERE cardNo IS NOT NULL
AND product_name IS NOT NULL
;
```

The select query returns valid results. However, when insert statement is added, I get the "Not a group by expression" error.

We have tried removing the where clause and the query worked after removing the same, however, we need the data filters to avoid duplicate data combinations at the target table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a typo, you're missing commas here:

```
 GROUP BY sd.order_date         --> here
   sd.order_id                  --> here
   sd.hour,
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It was a typo while posting the query here.

Comment: That's the only aggregation in this query, so it *should* be OK. It is difficult to guess as we don't have your tables nor data, but - as I said, it looks OK. Are you sure you didn't make yet another typo? If possible, post copy/past of your SQL Plus session so that we'd see what you exactly did and how Oracle responded.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue using /*+NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION*/ hint in the query